# Unable to connect to Apache(httpd) running inside VirtualBox Guest from LAN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, apache-http-server, port-forwarding

**Objective**
To be able to connect to httpd running inside a guest from other machines on the same LAN as the host.

**Approach taken**
I have configured a NAT interface with port forwarding on the guest. The host machine's port 8080 is being forwarded to the guest machines port 80.

The guest also has a host-only interface, this is used only to check if httpd's status (running/stopped) from the host.

I have the following **setup**:

- **Host** --> Fedora
- **Guest** --> Debian 9

  - Network interfaces (2)
  - NAT
  - Host Only
- **Port forwarding**
  Host Port 8080 forwarded to Guest Port 80

**Issue**
I am unable to access port 80 on the guest from the host (by using localhost:8080, i.e., without using the host-only interface), consequently, it is accessible from LAN either.

That said, i also have ssh on the guest, I tried the same port forwarding setup for ssh,i.e, forward Host:8080 to Guest:22 and it worked! I can SSH into the guest from the Host and also from other machines on the same LAN. So it doesn't seem to be a firewall issue.

I have got httpd listening on 0.0.0.0:80 via /etc/apache2/ports.conf. I have also tried changing the port httpd listens on without much luck.Similarly, I have also tried specifying the IP Address httpd listens to as the IP Assigned by VirtualBox to the NAT interface without much lick either.

I have tried creating a new NAT interface from File>Preference>Network and also by adding port forwarding to the default NAT interface built into VirtualBox.

Running a wget on the host gives the following output

```
# wget localhost:8080
--2017-08-08 13:06:33--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://localhost/ [following]
--2017-08-08 13:06:34--  http://localhost/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

The excerpts of the output produced by the netstat command on the Host and Guest are
Host machine:

```
Local Address       Foreign Address      State
192.168.1.2:8080    192.168.1.2:52162    FIN_WAIT2
```

Guest machine:

```
Local Address       Foreign Address      State
10.0.2.15:80        10.0.2.2:52162       FIN_WAIT2
```

So the connection is being forwarded to the guest? There is no firewall on the guest (iptables -L returns an empty list). SSH being accessible while httpd not being accessible probably means it is a httpd configuration issue?

What could i possibly be missing here?

Comment: if I undestood well you need to set the guest network adapter as a bridge, this is because the guest and the host are isolated from physical ports unless you perform the connection as a bridge. Once you set the port you'll be able to listen for that port as the host do, so you only need to set the network configuration to set it on the same network you need.